# How to center vertically and fill a background color to an Area Type Tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, background, alignment

This is the `Area Type Tool` I've created:

[image]

I'd like to:

1. Center it (also) vertically, so if I resize the width/height area it will keep both the vertical and horizontal alignments
2. Add a background color to the area (red, for example)

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Direct Selection Tool** > Select the text frame > choose a filling color

[image: Txt area]

Comment: Not sure why, but when I click on "red" it colors the text, not the background :(

Comment: Use the **Direct Selection Tool**, but click exactly at the text field border, if you can't use the **Outline View Mode**. The selection frame is different than selecting a text field.

Comment: I did. But the background color doesn't change :O

Comment: If you still in outline view Mode you will not see any color

Comment: I'm not in Outline View Mode (CTRL+Y).

Comment: No matter, now it works! Dunno why. It seems a bug: if I start with a rectangle with filled color, than later (after insert area type tool) it won't change the color. Fixed, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of tricky in AI CS6. Both native features in InDesign.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In illustrator I would make the background an independent rectangle and center the text over it.

This will give you more control of borders and spacing.

Center justify your text:

[image]

Make a rectangle, select both it and your text and align both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

This text can be edited or resized and will remain centered on the rectangle.

Comment: Every time I change the text size, I need to realign, right? Or can be automatic?

Comment: No if the text is both center justified and center aligned with the background rectangle than stays centered when you resize it

Comment: How do you center "respect" another object? (such the rectangle)

Comment: I changed the picture to show the align tool. Two objects can be selected and center aligned with each other

Comment: Yes, but "in that moment". Once I resize the text, it lost the alignment between text and rectangle. I need to redo the selection+alignment. They are not "linked" forever :O